# A map between Brauer groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group, brauer-groups

Let $R$ be a henselian dvr over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ be a flat $R$-algebra of finite type. Suppose $\hat{R}$ is the completion of $R$ and $\hat{A}:=A\otimes_R \hat{R}$. For an ideal $I\subseteq A$, assume $A/I$ is flat over $R$. By the map $R\to \hat{R}$, there is a natural map
$$ \gamma:\mathrm{Br}'(\mathrm{Spec}\,A\setminus V(I))\to \mathrm{Br}'(\mathrm{Spec}\,\hat{A}\setminus V(\hat{I})),$$
where $\hat{I}:=I\hat{A}$ and $\mathrm{Br}'(X):=H^2_{et}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ for a scheme $X$. Is $\gamma$ an injection? If it is not true, does it true that the restriction of $\gamma$
$$ \gamma|_{\mathrm{tor}}:\mathrm{Br}'(\mathrm{Spec}\,A\setminus V(I))_{\mathrm{tor}}\to \mathrm{Br}'(\mathrm{Spec}\,\hat{A}\setminus V(\hat{I}))_{\mathrm{tor}}$$
to the torsion parts of the Brauer groups is an injection? My motivation is to prove the following map
$$ \mathrm{Pic}(\mathrm{Spec}\,A\setminus V(I))_{\mathrm{tor}}\to \mathrm{Pic}(\mathrm{Spec}\,\hat{A}\setminus V(\hat{I}))_{\mathrm{tor}}$$
is an isomorphism for good cases. For any prime $\ell$ and any positive integer $n$, using the Kummer sequence, we have a diagram
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
&0\to \mathrm{Pic}(\mathrm{Spec}\,A\setminus V(I))[\ell^n]\to H^2_{et}(\mathrm{Spec}\,A\setminus V(I),\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n)\to \mathrm{Br}'(\mathrm{Spec}\,A\setminus V(I))\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\downarrow\,\alpha\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\downarrow\,\beta\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\downarrow\,\gamma \\
& 0\to \mathrm{Pic}(\mathrm{Spec}\,\hat{A}\setminus V(\hat{I}))[\ell^n]\to H^2_{et}(\mathrm{Spec}\,\hat{A}\setminus V(\hat{I}),\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n)\to \mathrm{Br}'(\mathrm{Spec}\,\hat{A}\setminus V(\hat{I})).
\end{aligned}
$$
If $\beta$ is an isomorphism and $\gamma$ is an injection, we can prove that $\alpha$ is a surjection by the five lemma. In my intuition, $\beta$ is not an isomorphism for many cases but $\gamma$ is always an injection. Can we give proof of injectivity of $\gamma$ or a counterexample that $\gamma$ is not an injection?